# How do I add the values calculated in a for loop in a array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm currently writing a code in MATLAB that plots the convergence of 1/N!, Where N goes from 1-10. I've created a for loop that calculates 1/N! for each value from 1-10 but how do I add each of the values calcuated in the for loop in a vector array?

```
clc,clear
Nterms = 10;
total = 0;

for ns = 0:Nterms
    newterm = 1/(factorial(ns));
    disp(['The term ',num2str(ns),' is:',num2str(newterm)])
    total = total + newterm; % Sum of series
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate array before the loop (initialize with zeros), and put values to array using `ns+1` as index:

```
clc,clear
Nterms = 10;
total = 0;

% Initialize the array with zeros - allocate memory space
arr = zeros(1, Nterms+1);

for ns = 0:Nterms
    newterm = 1/(factorial(ns));
    disp(['The term ',num2str(ns),' is:',num2str(newterm)])
    total = total + newterm; % Sum of series

    % Store newterm in index ns+1 of arr.
    arr(ns + 1) = newterm;
end

disp(arr);
```

Comment: Ahhh I was along the right line with prelocating the vector size, Thanks you for your help!